# Inbound rules for a port is configured and disabled yet an NMap scan shows that the port is opened

Tags: windows, firewalls, nmap, ports

I am new to Windows Defender but have read about it to understand the basics of Inbound/Outbound rules.

As mentioned on the app, Inbound connections that do not match a rule are simply blocked.

For my system, I have few number of inbound rules for port 135 AND of these rules are disabled. Which if I understand correctly, will be closed for all the services coming through the port?

Yet an NMap scan shows that port 135 is open.

I think I am missing something here - maybe my understanding of open/closed ports is not correct. Appreciate any help or resources!

Comment: You probably port scanned on local ip and not public ip

Comment: @Malabika Sen What are the active rules? Did you check if they are permissive? Also as Vipul pointed out above, are you running scans on 'localhost'?

Comment: Hi, I am not running scans on a localhost per se but yeah, these are the IPs of my private local network. Yes, they are not public IPs. Where can I see the active rules? @VipulNair

Comment: @hax - I understand that you mean firewall rules when you said active rules. Like I mentioned in the post, all of the rules for port 135 are disabled.

Comment: @MalabikaSen Try and port scan public ip.If it is closed then it is closed for everyone that is not on the same network.As for blocking for everyone including devices on the same network.There are firewall rules you can set for that as well.The implementation would be different for whatever you are using

Comment: @VipulNair as far as I understand, port scan on a public IP will not necessarily target the particular computer because of NAT? Since, behind the router all the devices in the network appear as one?

Comment: Yes most isp implement that if you are behind NAT your ports will be closed for the outside world

Comment: I realized that for one computer, the inbound rules was not activated for  a private profile. But, after I turned it on as well, port 135 still shows open. Can you tell me if I'm going wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Malabika Sen The likelihood is that there is another active rule which permits connections to that port.

Comment: I am looking into the rules more, but as I have said all rules for port 135 are disabled :(